# How to limit statistics in Gatling report to steady state

Tags: benchmarking, gatling

I have a classical Gatling benchmark setup, I ramp users for a while and then keep a constant rate. In the very nice reports Gatling shows, there are some stats but IIUC these cover the whole scenario - not just steady state. Is it possible to limit this to only certain part of the scenario? (basically just ignore all requests started or finished before and after this period?) Or do I have to manually truncate the simulation logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's only available in FrontLine, our commercial product. You can get stats on any time window.